# Скрипт перезапуска SERVICE NETWORK

Tags: linux, bash

Необходим скрипт для сервера на Centos, который будет пинговать к примеру сайт yandex.ru, и как только ответ от сайта пропал (нет ответа секунд 15), перезапускать сетевую службу (service network restart) до тех пор, пока связь не восстановится.

P.S Пинговать не по крону, а постоянно, и как только связь пропадает - рестарт

Comment: Как-то мне кажется, что циклический рестарт сервисов на самом деле не решит Вашу проблему

(которую, Вы тут и не описали).

--

Что на самом-то деле у Вас происходит, а что Вы хотите?

Comment: именно! придерживаюсь такого же мнения как и @avp  
А перезапуск сети в современном CentOS  уже давно проводится командой service NetworkManager restart

Comment: Как понять "циклический", и ка его запускать ТОЛЬКО тогда, когда пропадает пинг?

Justicet, вот объясните мне, я нахожусь в Москве, а сервер стоит в Питере, как я удалённо перезагружу сеть, если сеть не работает?

Comment: @Nicolayka, циклический -- это означает, что как только пинг пропал, Вы перезапускаете network.

Я еще раз хочу обратить Ваше внимание на то, что это **ничего не изменит** (даже если реализовать этот рестарт "умно"). ОС и сеть это не рыба, которая тухнет сама по себе.

Если недоступность сервера связана с сетевым оборудованием, то service network restart ничего не даст. 

Нужно понять причину проблему и устранять ее.

Comment: Там проблема у провайдера, падает DNS, и перезапускается через некоторое время, а мой сервак пытается раз 50 получить IP, и прекращает, а DNS ещё не восстановился у провайдера. Вот и приходится звонить сис. админу, что бы он вручную перезагрузил сеть. Но это уже надоедает, и надо написать скрипт, который сам будет пинговать внешний ресурс, и как только связь пропала, перезагружать сеть до тех пор, пока связь не восстановится.

Comment: так падает DNS ? поставьте свой или используйте публичный DNS, причем тут ping ?

Comment: У провайдера всё сложно. Я попросил конкретно помочь со скриптом, а не предлагать мне ставить свой DNS

Comment: Он не хочет. Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: На месте Яндекса, я порезал бы данному пользователю ICMP. Шутки ради.

Если взять тон более серьёзный, то грамотные сетевики знают, через что они подклчены к Интернету, и если что и пингуют в таких автоматических ловушках, то только то, что близко к ним расположено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот информация

ping -w 5 -c 3 yandex.ru

ведет себя так : если в течении 5 секунд было 3 или больше ответов, то в $? будет 0, если было меньше 3х ответов, то в $? будет 1

пингуйте и проверяйте $? в цикле `while :;do cmd;done`  и перезапускайте сервис если надо,

настройте supervisord чтобы постоянно держал ваш скрипт запущеным.

[условия в bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)

[цикл while](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29)

[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-example)

Comment: Спасибо большое, но есть проблемка, я не так давно с Линуксом, и да, я не программист. Если Вам не сложно будет, я был бы очень признателен, если бы Вы написали сам скрипт. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: я бы вам был очень признателен, если бы вы оплатили мою работу, в эквиваленте 50$/час на биткоин. 

> [Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не является фриланс-биржей.](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)

Answer (score 0):

start on started network-manager stop on runlevel [016] script while true; do if ifconfig eth0 | grep -q "inet addr:"; then # echo "all ok!" else restart network-manager fi sleep 5 done end scrip

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]